# Why is git log not working with a subexpression

Tags: git, powershell

```
git tag --list 'Release-v*' --sort=-creatordate | Select-Object -First 1
```

gives me the latest tag with name matching Release-v*. In my case thats Release-v2024.3.12.132

If I use

```
git log Release-v2024.3.12.132..HEAD
```

I get the expected log entries from tag till head

However if I combine these wo commands

```
git log $(git tag --list 'Release-v*' --sort=-creatordate | Select-Object -First 1)..HEAD
```

, I get no output at all (also no error)
I already tried `().Trim()` the git tag command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest the `<tag>..HEAD` expression in a string literal to prevent PowerShell's parser from interpreting `<tag>` and `..HEAD` as two separate arguments:

```
git log "$(git tag --list 'Release-v*' --sort=-creatordate | Select-Object -First 1)..HEAD"
```

---

How do I know that PowerShell interprets `<tag>..HEAD` as 2 separate arguments?

I know thanks to the power of PowerShell's built-in tracing facility!
Let's try and inspect the command with [the `Trace-Command` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command):

```
PS ~> Trace-Command -Expression { git log $latestTag..Head } -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:22.7471 ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED native application line args [C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe]
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:22.7475 ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND cmd line arg [log] to position [0]
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:22.7483 ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND cmd line arg [vTagName] to position [1]
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:22.7513 ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND cmd line arg [..HEAD] to position [2]
```

Here we see that the expression evaluated as `vTagName` is treated as a stand-alone argument value separate from the argument value `..HEAD`

Let's try it again with the whole thing nested in a string literal:

```
PS ~> Trace-Command -Expression { git log "$latestTag..Head" } -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:30.3736 ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED native application line args [C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe]
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:30.3740 ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND cmd line arg [log] to position [0]
DEBUG: 2024-03-19 12:25:30.3750 ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND cmd line arg [vTagName..HEAD] to position [1]
```

And here we see the resulting string value `vTagName..HEAD` now correctly passed as a single positional argument.

Comment: awesome! works like expected + I learned about the Trace-Command

Comment: That tracing functionality looks cool. Thanks for showing all the steps.

Comment: @Guildenstern My pleasure! The `ParameterBinding` tracer represents just a small corner of PowerShell's tracing facility, play around with it and try different (smaller) snippets with `-Name * -PSHost`